# Dell Inspiron wifi on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, drivers, dell

I have freshly installed ubuntu 15.10 on my Dell Inspiron 14z. Wired connection works fine, drivers for the wifi seem to work as well (networks are visible and once even the connection at home was established). Nevertheless, the first successful attempt was the last one. Any time since my home wifi is visible, asks for a password and when the password is given, it asks for it again after like seconds without making a connection.

Already tried (without any success):

- restarting notebook, restarting modem
- asking the wifi options to forget the network settings and set them anew

Any ideas, please?

**Edit:**

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 OK, done.

Comment: I saw, but I do not have ideas. Sometime this happens to Broadcom users. Try to change the password in the router. Sometimes it starts to work mysteriously.

Answer (score 0):

It seems so far that it is a driver-router cooperation problem (as Pilot6 suggested). Simple password change did not help, but the fixed channel choice does.